# Models in the Zend Framework inner join query

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have two tables i want to write a inner join query in zend to fetch all record from table 1 whose id does not matches with table 2 id

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();       
$select = $db->select()->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE); 
$select->from('cwi_company','*')->join('cwi_groupinglinks','cwi_company.id <> cwi_groupinglinks.orgId')->where('cwi_company.manage=1')->where('cwi_company.deleteOption=0');
$result =$select->fetchAll();       
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `joinInner` for inner joins

```
$select->from('cwi_company','*')->joinInner('cwi_groupinglinks','cwi_company.id != cwi_groupinglinks.orgId')->where('cwi_company.manage=1')->where('cwi_company.deleteOption=0');
```

Comment: join is the alias for joinInner

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select records which does not exist in right table, you need to Left Join and select where value == NULL, for ex:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();       

$select = $db->select()->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE); 
$select->from('cwi_company','*')
  ->joinLeft('cwi_groupinglinks','cwi_company.id = cwi_groupinglinks.orgId')
  ->where('cwi_company.manage=1')
  ->where('cwi_company.deleteOption=0');
  ->where('cwi_groupinglinks.orgId IS NULL')

$result = $select->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit tweaked version of @Aurimas Ličkus answer

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();       

$select = $db->select()->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE); 
$select->from('cwi_company',array('*'))
  ->joinLeft('cwi_groupinglinks','cwi_company.id = cwi_groupinglinks.orgId',null)
  ->where('cwi_company.manage = ?',1)
  ->where('cwi_company.deleteOption = ?',0);
  ->where('cwi_groupinglinks.orgId IS NULL')

$result = $select->fetchAll();

return (!empty($result)) ? $result : null;
```